# AngularJS: Change decimal separator to comma

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internationalization, decimalformat

I hope I get a solution for this.
I am using `angular1.4`.

I want to display time in decimal numbers(separated by comma because users are in Germany-Europe).

For example 5min is expected to be displayed as:

**5min=(5/60)=0,08** (2 decimal places)

Then I came across this solution: [AngularJS number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number). However the result appears in decimal, what can I add to this pipe filter below, to change/replace decimal to comma?

```
<span>{{ dr.duration/(60*60*1000) | number:2}}</span>
```

In case you need clarity lemme know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the separators used by the AngularJS number filter, include the appropriate locale rule set such as `angular-locale_de-de.js`.

There are two approaches to providing locale rules to AngularJS:

- [Pre-bundled rule sets](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n#1-pre-bundled-rule-sets)
- [Including a locale script in `index.html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n#2-including-a-locale-script-in-index-html-)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Providing locale rules to AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n#providing-locale-rules-to-angularjs)
- [AngularJS number Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

## The DEMO

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <span><b>5min=(5/60)=</b>
      {{ 5/60 | number:2 }} hr (2 decimal places)
    </span>
</body>
```

Comment: I added this answer in a weird situation where the client does not want to use locale services(like my case). https://stackoverflow.com/a/55261028/6561825

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation for the [$locale](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/service/$locale) service.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/v1.4.0/src/ngLocale)'s a list of locales in the source code.

The [example](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/guide/i18n) that they use for supported locales is actually for Germany :~).

Btw, In the AngularJS docs there's a button at the top of each page that says [view source code] at the top of each page.

Comment: Thank you @Saylestyler. But for now the project doesn't include this service and it might take time before my PO does it(a project with a lot of restriction/bureaucracies), is there another way around to just work with just this component?

Comment: So I found another way to do it without locale service.
I added this answer in a weird situation where the client does not want to use locale services(like my case). https://stackoverflow.com/a/55261028/6561825

Comment: amazing, great solution

Answer (score 0):

So I found another way to do it without locale service.
I added this pipe

```
app.filter('timeToDecimals', ($filter) => {
    return function (input) {
      let time = Number(input);
        if (!Number.isNaN(time)) {
            let number = time/(60*60*1000);
            return $filter('number')(number, 2).replace(".",",");
        } 
        else return '00,00';
    }
});
```

Where the input is from duration.

I hope this helps someone out there.